# How to do an Ansible condition test of user/group existence?

Tags: ansible

As new nodes (CentOS 7.6) are added, there are basic groups and users that need to be created. Some of the nodes have some of the groups and users.  I would like to only create the groups and users on the nodes where they don't exist via my Ansible (version 2.8.0) basic role file.

Currently, I'm testing for the group/user, but the there's always a "fatal" printed and my conditionals don't appear to work.

roles/basic/tasks/main.yml

```
- name: "Does k8s group exist?"
  shell: grep -q "^k8s" /etc/group
  register: gexist

- name: "Create k8s group"
  shell: groupadd -g 8000 k8s
  when: gexist.rc != 0    

- name: "Does k8s user exist?"
  shell: id -u k8s > /dev/null 2>&1
  register: uexist

- name: "Create k8s user"
  shell: useradd -g 8000 -d /home/k8s -s /bin/bash -u 8000 -m k8s
  when: uexist.rc != 0
```

which yields:

```
TASK [basic : Does k8s group exist?] *****************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [master]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "grep -q \"^k8s:\" /etc/group", "delta": "0:00:00.009424", "end": "2019-05-29 14:42:17.947350", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2019-05-29 14:42:17.937926", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
fatal: [node3]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "grep -q \"^k8s:\" /etc/group", "delta": "0:00:00.012089", "end": "2019-05-29 06:41:36.661356", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2019-05-29 06:41:36.649267", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
fatal: [node1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "grep -q \"^k8s:\" /etc/group", "delta": "0:00:00.010104", "end": "2019-05-29 14:42:17.990460", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2019-05-29 14:42:17.980356", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
changed: [node2]
```

There has got to be a better to do conditionals (if-then-else) than the way I'm doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [user](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/user_module.html#user-manage-user-accounts) and [group](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/group_module.html#group-add-or-remove-groups). The code below is probably what you're looking for.

```
- name: "Create k8s group"
  group:
    gid: 8000
    name: k8s

- name: "Create k8s user"
  user:
    group: k8s
    home: /home/k8s
    shell: /bin/bash
    uid: 8000
    name: k8s
```

The only `if-then-else` in Ansible I'm aware of is the [ternary](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id8) filter (for other options see [jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/)).  The control flow is rather poor in Ansible compared to other procedural languages. It's because of the code rather defines a state of the system then a procedure.

To answer your question:

> How to do an Ansible condition test of user/group existence?

Your code does it correctly, but the purpose of Ansible is to define the state of the system. It's not important a user or group existed before or not. After successfully having run the code they will exist (definition of a state) and running the code again makes sure they still exist (audit).